# Change formatting of a column to text

Tags: excel, vba

Every time I run this code the entire sheet becomes Text.

I want to keep the rest of the sheet General, but change column A to Text.

For the

```
Columns("A").Select _
  ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "@"
```

I tried

```
 Range("A:A").Select
 Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
```

I tried writing it with the specific workbook instead of letting VBA assume the active worksheet and cells.

I tried to NumberFormat the other columns to be General after running the formatting on column A.

```
Columns("A").Select
Range("A1").Activate
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

Columns("A").Select
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "@"
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CommandBars("Office Clipboard").Visible = False
```

I expected that if I put another line after my numberformat that I would be able to get column B:ZZ to all be General.

I've gotten no error messages.

Comment: Please learn how to write code avoiding the use of `select`.. In saying that, you can simply write `Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "@"`

Comment: [How to avoid using select in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/62576)

Comment: @KenWhite thanks. I need to save that link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested these, both work.  Formulas referencing the affected cells do not compute, formulas referencing other numeric cells are calculating as normal.

```
Range("A:A").NumberFormat="@"

Range("A1").EntireColumn.NumberFormat="@"
```